# Adding object to model, doesn't update dom

Tags: angularjs

I have a method that creates an object and pushes it to an array

```
$scope.contracts = [];
$scope.addContract = function () {
        var contract = {
            ...
        }

        $scope.contracts.push(contract);

        console.log($scope.contracts);

    }
```

now in my DOM, i have the following (merely for debugging)

```
{{contracts}}
```

But this doesn't update. I validate in the console, that the object is in the array.
Why doesn't the model update?
I've already tried various applications of $scope.$apply, but they all result in an

```
$apply already in progress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must be wrong with your code, check your DOM. Does anything happen when you call your function? Heres is a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("test", function($scope){
  $scope.contracts = [];
  $scope.addContract = function () {
  var contract = {
      "con":"tract"
  }
  $scope.contracts.push(contract);
  
  console.log($scope.contracts);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="test">
    {{contracts}}
    
    <button ng-click="addContract()">Add contract</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I found an error in my controller that deleted the array, right after i added the object. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks for the answer